# Android xml layout for listView

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm sorry if I ask a silly quuestion here. I have created one `listView` in my Activity which used to load the values from `SQLite`.

How do I move the `Pro-xxx`(Retrieve_details) below `press the list for edit` ? Thanks

[image]

**Edit_details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tomato"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:text="Press the list for edit" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:id="@+id/listViewEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />


</FrameLayout>
```

**Retrieve_details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Project"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Progress: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Time In: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Time Out: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Project"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Percentage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="TextView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Added button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id = "@+id/rl_top"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tomato"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:text="Press the list for edit" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:text="Add Claims"
            android:width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:id="@+id/listViewEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />


</RelativeLayout >
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1">

    <LinearLayout
     android:background="#4b14b1"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:id = "@+id/rl_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tomato"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:text="Press the list for edit" />
    <Button 
android:background="#4b14b1"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="100dp"
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:text="ss"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
       android:layout_below="@+id/rl_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:id="@+id/listViewEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />


</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question ? I want to add a button beside `TextView`. I tried this code but failed. `<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="100sp"/>`

Comment: I added button.For newer, use LinearLayout.

Comment: Can you see my post again? The button (grey color) looked weird :?

Comment: I edited .          android:layout_width="209dp"         =>android:layout_width="match_parent" .It is because its parent with is not enough.

Comment: It doesn't make any different ...T.T

Comment: I edited .add some background  textColor on button and LinearLayout to see space them get.

Comment: Thanks!! But how to adjust it ? I just want the button next to textView, and I don't want to have such a big linear layout >< thanks

Comment: LinearLayout match_parent => wrap_content;button 200dp=>wrap_content

Comment: Show me your layout and screenshot

Comment: please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160017/adjust-xml-layout-and-place-an-icon-button-inside-imageview/34160495#34160495

Comment: where the chat gone ?

Answer (score 1):

try this in pro-xxx textview in xml:

```
android:layout_below="@id/idOfAboveView"
```

here id is of your textview: "press the list for edit"

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` as root element and use `android:layout_below` attr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="461dp"
        android:id="@+id/listViewEdit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/listViewEdit"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/tomato"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:text="Press the list for edit" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```