# Adjust xml layout and place an icon button inside ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Can someone please help me to adjust my xml layout ? I need seriously help.

This is how my xml looked like

[image]

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/dark_blue"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter Claims Information"
        android:id="@+id/textViewClaims"
        android:paddingTop="30sp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="340sp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100sp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Claims Type : "
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textViewClaimsType"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="342dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40sp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Claims Amount :"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textViewAmount"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
        android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="7458dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Enter Description"
        android:paddingTop="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_x="14dp"
        android:layout_y="146dp"
        android:id="@+id/textDescription" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="159dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="save"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Problem:**

1. How to move the spinner to right hand sight?
2. Move the white line between enter claims and claims type to right
3. Narrow down the space between `editTextAmount` below `ClaimsAmount` text
4. Image View doesn't show. It should place below `editTextAmount`
5. How to add an icon `button` inside `imageView` ?

I'm sorry if I ask a lot here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**After use @tiny answer**

[image]

Comment: please add the screen shot how you want

Comment: @Ishan I want to move the spinner and the line slightly to the right, and add an imageView after `editTextAmount`. The imageView should be in center.

Comment: I add a layout for you , you should replace all sp to dp .  dp is better.

Comment: @tinysunlight How do I make the button inside imageView to bottom?

Comment: set gravity to bottom and if you need some space use layout_marginBottom. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/dark_blue"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Claims Information"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClaims"
            android:paddingTop="30sp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <View
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_width="340sp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Claims Type : "
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClaimsType"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Claims Amount :"
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAmount"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="323dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
            android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
            <Button
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="159dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="save"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_weight="0.05" />
        </FrameLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Description"
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="325dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_x="14dp"
            android:layout_y="146dp"
            android:id="@+id/textDescription" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="159dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171499/emulator-run-slowly-when-come-to-a-specific-layout) ? I using the answer you provided but emulator  run slowly. You have any idea for this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, Linear Layout arranges the views linearly, one after the other, where as in Relative Layout you can customize the child views (like `ImageView`, `Spinner` etc) as you wish. You can position them anywhere in the screen if you use `RelativeLayout`

You are not seeing a image because you did not supply a image to you image view. Here is documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src)

Answer (score 0):

Add Margin left -

```
      <Spinner
            android:layout_width="342dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" 
            android:id="@+id/spinner" />
```

Add image to your image view. It will get visible as right now it is wrap content. whenever you are giving padding or margin , use dp not sp.

Comment: I accept tiny answer since her answer more fulfill with my questions. I will give you upvote for sure :)