# Emulator run slowly when come to a specific layout

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator, emulation

I don't know what's wrong with my `xml` layout. Everytime when it intent to **AddMoreClaims** activity, my emulator will run slowly and sometimes not responding as image shown below.

[image]

And this are the `logCat` message

```
12-09 05:05:59.758    2688-2688/? E/RichInputConnection﹕ Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
12-09 05:05:59.758    2688-2688/? W/RichInputConnection﹕ Unable to connect to the editor. Setting caps mode without knowing text.
12-09 05:05:59.760    2688-2688/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 352 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-09 05:05:59.783    2688-2710/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-09 05:05:59.784    2688-2710/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa30bfe80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-09 05:06:03.080    2808-2808/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 153 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-09 05:06:08.163    2808-2808/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 151 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-09 05:06:10.863    2808-2808/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 161 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/dark_blue"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Claims Information"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClaims"
            android:paddingTop="30sp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <View
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="340sp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Claims Type : "
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClaimsType"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="308dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Claims Amount :"
            android:paddingTop="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAmount"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="308dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
            android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.09" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add picture"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Description"
            android:paddingTop="30sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="308dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_square"
            android:layout_weight="0.12"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_x="14dp"
            android:layout_y="146dp"
            android:id="@+id/textDescription" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="159dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Why would this happen and how can I solve it ? Thanks

Comment: Post the class corresponding to this xml

Comment: @Jas I did not implement anything in this class yet

Comment: Try  to use a phone . And it seems like you do too many action  in UiThread.

Comment: @tinysunlight Is there any way  to prevent this ?

Comment: you should provide you activity or fragment relate to this layout.

Comment: @tinysunlight I did not implement any thing yet, only these three line  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_claims_here);`}

Comment: So try to use real phone. Emulator is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

> Layouts are a key part of Android applications that directly affect
>   the user experience. If implemented poorly, your layout can lead to a
>   memory hungry application with slow UIs. The Android SDK includes
>   tools to help you identify problems in your layout performance, which
>   when combined the lessons here, you will be able to implement smooth
>   scrolling interfaces with a minimum memory footprint.

### Loading Views On Demand

> Beyond simply including one layout component within another layout,
>   you might want to make the included layout visible only when it's
>   needed, sometime after the activity is running. This lesson shows how
>   you can improve your layout's initialization performance by loading
>   portions of your layout on demand.

**Wrong Concept**

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add picture"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />
```

In here you are using `android:layout_weight`, Well .Then another case you set Hard coded **height & Width** ,That's why have problem . Avoid Hard coded Value .

Comment: How should I write if I wanted to have a button below `imageView` ?

Comment: You can use `android:layout_below` (Relative Layout) & use real device

Comment: Increase your RAM Size in your Virtual device